# Restarting the app server getting error?

Tags: java, mysql

we are getting error when restarting the app server.

generally when we restart the app server it will create connections itself.

but it was throwing below error.

```
2013-11-05 04:06:00,029 WARN  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool] (pool-11-thread-1) Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'jade2.ftdi.com' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'")

Observed below log also:
2013-11-05 04:07:18,074 INFO  [STDOUT] (pool-11-thread-1) DEBUG 2013-11-05 04:07:18,074 [pool-11-thread-1] com.ftd.core.datasource.model.DataSourceHealthMonitor: doDBServerMaintenance path to db server maintenance files jboss.server.data.dir
2013-11-05 04:07:18,074 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-12) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2013-11-05 04:07:20,844 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8713-2) ERROR 2013-11-05 04:07:16,673 [http-0.0.0.0-8713-2] com.ftd.core.datasource.exceptionhandlers.NormalExecutionHandler: Caught TransactionException.org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is com.ftd.core.datasource.exceptions.ConnectionException: nested exception is com.ftd.core.datasource.exceptions.DataSourceException: All Databases are down!!!
```

After this error Our DBA'S issued flush hosts; in DB side but no luck still we are getting same error.how fix it

Comment: Apart from database connection issue, application is facing memory shortage too. Try providing -Xmx and -Xms with some higher memory and restart your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Maybe you should try to increase the heap size of VM